# How can I preserve NEHotspotHelperCommand

Tags: ios, networkextension

Am using Network Extension framework in my app, the hotspot helper commands are received properly on latch and unlatch from desired SSID and the command is than bind with my request object.
The problem arrises as I quit and relaunch my app as at that point the old command is lost and I don't receive a new command until latch/unlatch occurs for desired SSID. Can I somehow preserve the old command or generate a new command on app launch ?

Comment: I also want to do the same. Did you got any thing on it?